# Matlab Image Segmenter morphology

Tags: matlab, image-segmentation

Im trying to segment an image into three categories using Matlab Image Segmenter.

The raw image:

[image]

Three categories are as follows:
1. Large white shapes
2. Small white shapes
3. Background

I have managed to segment Large shapes using tresholding and morphology options.

[image]

And backround using tresholding and inverse mask

[image]

However I don't know how to segment small shapes from the image. Morphology option allows to segment shapes larger than some treshold value, but does not allow to segment shapes smaller than treshold value, or in between.

I need to treshold more than 100 of these images so manual filling is not an option.

Comment: But wouldn't everything that is not the background or the bigger white stripes be the small white stripes?

Comment: Yes exactly, but I can't find appropriate tools in the Image Segmenter to express that logic. I can't find any option that would allow to add or substract masks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one solution. If your other segmentation steps already work, you can export all the steps to a function. Save function, and just add the logic yourself. If `BW1` corresponds to the large shapes, `BW2` to the background, then the small shapes correspond to:

```
BW3 = ~(BW1 | BW1);
```